# Date format on INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following SELECT statement works and returns the date in the correct FORMAT.

```
SELECT 
' - '+c.[customercli] 
,c.[customerlookup]  
,c.[customername] 
,c.[linedescription] 
,c.[Sum of buy price] 
,c.[Sum of sell price]  
,c.[qty] 
,c.[Billingmonth] 
,FORMAT([FromDate],'dd/MM/yyyy') 
,FORMAT([ToDate],'dd/MM/yyyy') 

FROM [MasterBill].[dbo].[DaisyCallsCurrentBill] c
```

But when I run the following INSERT / SELECT statement, I get the following error.

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

```
INSERT INTO [MasterBill].[dbo].[CurrentBillMaster]
([identifier]
,[customer id]
,[customer name]
,[description]
,[buy price]
,[sell price]
,[qty]
,[Billingmonth]
,[FromDate]
,[ToDate]) 

SELECT 
' - '+c.[customercli] 
,c.[customerlookup]  
,c.[customername] 
,c.[linedescription] 
,c.[Sum of buy price] 
,c.[Sum of sell price]  
,c.[qty] 
,c.[Billingmonth] 
,FORMAT([FromDate],'dd/MM/yyyy') 
,FORMAT([ToDate],'dd/MM/yyyy') 

FROM [MasterBill].[dbo].[DaisyCallsCurrentBill] c
```

The FromDate and ToDate on both tables are configured with a type of "date"

Any help greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: the date is in the following format on the [dbo].[DaisyCallsCurrentBill] table 2014-09-01 - I simply want to change this to 01/09/2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it looks like you are inserting date which is in string type. Remove the format function and it should work. Why? **Formatting** is just a way to **represent** the date. Database stores date in its own way, you cannot change it.

Comment: But the format in my dB table is 2014-09-01 - I need it to be 01/09/2014.

Comment: 2014-09-01 is a way database **shows** the date. If you want to see it in 01/09/2014, then you use formatting. Read [this](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery) and [this](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server/). Hope it helps.

Comment: @user3580480 -In database Date will be stored in `yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` only. If you want change the way it stores then change your datatype to varchar but that makes no sense. All these Formatting has to be done only on Front End while displaying. why are you really worried about the way it is stored

Answer (score 0):

Since you're selecting a `date` field and attempting to insert it to another `date` field, formatting is meaningless, and shouldn't be used:

```
INSERT INTO [MasterBill].[dbo].[CurrentBillMaster]
([identifier]
,[customer id]
,[customer name]
,[description]
,[buy price]
,[sell price]
,[qty]
,[Billingmonth]
,[FromDate]
,[ToDate]) 

SELECT 
' - '+c.[customercli] 
,c.[customerlookup]  
,c.[customername] 
,c.[linedescription] 
,c.[Sum of buy price] 
,c.[Sum of sell price]  
,c.[qty] 
,c.[Billingmonth] 
,c.[FromDate], -- Note: no formatting
,c.[ToDate] -- here too

FROM [MasterBill].[dbo].[DaisyCallsCurrentBill] c
```

Comment: But the format in my dB table is 2014-09-01 - I need it to be 01/09/2014

Comment: There is no such thing as "the format in the table" - it's a `date`, not a string. What you're seeing is the database's default format. If you need to display a different format, just format it when querying, like you did in the first query in the question.